# JPA Inheritance. Setting value Exeption in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm getting the following exception when attempting to persist an entity during a JUnit test.  I'm using Eclipselink 2.5.2.  I cant find what might be causing this exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-32] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Trying to set value [165.0] for instance variable [doubleValue] of type [java.lang.Double] in the object.  The specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, or an unwrapping conversion has failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Double field ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.DoubleListValue.doubleValue to ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.ExtraHumidity
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[doubleValue-->ta_ams_weather_list_parameters.double_value]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.ExtraTemperature --> [DatabaseTable(ta_ams_weather_list_parameters)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.helper.EntityManagerHelper.commitTransaction(EntityManagerHelper.java:41)
    at ar.asimov.acumar.ema.services.WeatherDataConsumer.run(WeatherDataConsumer.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-32] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Trying to set value [165.0] for instance variable [doubleValue] of type [java.lang.Double] in the object.  The specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, or an unwrapping conversion has failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Double field ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.DoubleListValue.doubleValue to ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.ExtraHumidity
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[doubleValue-->ta_ams_weather_list_parameters.double_value]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.ExtraTemperature --> [DatabaseTable(ta_ams_weather_list_parameters)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.illegalArgumentWhileSettingValueThruInstanceVariableAccessor(DescriptorException.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.setAttributeValueInObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1625)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.mergeIntoObject(AbstractDirectMapping.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4065)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:884)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4065)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeChangesIntoParent(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3280)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeChangesIntoParent(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Double field ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.DoubleListValue.doubleValue to ar.asimov.acumar.ema.model.ExtraHumidity
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(InstanceVariableAttributeAccessor.java:141)
    ... 21 more
```

I have the following classes in my model (i'm omitting the getters and setters 
for simplicity)

```
@IdClass(ListParameterValue.PrimaryKey.class)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, name="parameter_type",length=20)
@Table(name="ta_ams_weather_list_parameters")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class ListParameterValue implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static class PrimaryKey implements Serializable{...}

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="station_id",referencedColumnName="station_id")
    protected Station station;
    @Id
    @Column(name="date")
    protected LocalDate date;
    @Id
    @Column(name="start_time")
    protected LocalTime startTime;
    @Id
    @Column(name="order_index")
    protected Integer order;
    @Id
    @Column(name="parameter_type")
    protected String type;

}

@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class DoubleListValue extends ListParameterValue implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="double_value", nullable = true, columnDefinition="default null")
    protected Double doubleValue;

}

@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class ShortListValue extends ListParameterValue implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="short_value")
    protected Short shortValue; 

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("extra_humidity")
public class ExtraHumidity extends ShortListValue implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ExtraHumidity() {
     super();
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your test has a bug in that it is trying to create an instance of something that extends DoubleListValue and merge it in, but giving it and ID that already is used by an instance of ExtraHumidity.  This is illegal, as you cannot change the type of an entity without first removing and then re-inserting the entity.

We can't say how this occurs without seeing your test.

Comment: I've hit this issue now. If that'll help anybody, I inserted calls to         `((JpaCache)em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache()).clear();` between tests and that fixed the issue.